# php convert timestamp to specific format

Tags: php, mysql, timestamp

I have one field `registered_date` which is `timestamp` type in MYSQL. Now I an new with php I need your help.

I am getting this result: `2014-06-19 15:59:49`

and I want this output: 19 June 2014 15:59 PM

**Note: I am storing timestamp in php variable from sql query.**

Any Idea?

Answer (score 1):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php
http://php.net/manual/pl/function.date.php

```
$date = date('D M Y H:i A', strtotime($timestamp));
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you tagged the question with `mysql` here is the mysql solution, you can use [**date_format()**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) function while selecting the data and you will have desired format.

```
mysql> select date_format('2014-06-19 15:59:49','%d %M %Y %H:%i %p') as date ;
+-----------------------+
| date                  |
+-----------------------+
| 19 June 2014 15:59 PM |
+-----------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```